# Will turning HTML website to PHP slow it down?

Tags: php, html, performance

My new experimental blog ([The Homework Life](http://www.thehomeworklife.co.nf)) is currently an HTML page.

However, I want to add one or two short scripts in PHP. These scripts are also possible in JavaScript (such as getting `$_GET` variables), but are much more convenient in PHP.

I was wondering whether or not the switching of the file from a `.html` to a `.php` would slow it down (just because PHP is a server-side scripting language that the page would have to interpret first)? Disregarding the superficial times added by the PHP scripts, would the very act of adding PHP to it decrease page load time? (Or, if there's a way I can  test this myself, can you tell me?) Thanks.

Comment: Why was this downvoted so quickly (3 downvotes and two close votes in quick succession) without any explanation? What is wrong with this post? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading time is composed by many parts. There is a latency, the time the server takes to begin send the page back, the download time. Then there is an added time for every resource in the page (image, linked javascripts and css', etc).

In the case of a static HTML file, the server time will typically be inferior to 1ms. Changing the extension from `.html` to `.php` without doing anything else will typically double that time. When you add some PHP instruction to that file, the time will increase depending on the complexity of what you are doing with your PHP instructions.

Is it worth it? Probably yes, even if you get to 10ms of server time, it will still be a very little fraction of the total loading time. You won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Your server will have to load and run the PHP-Script. It will take more time until its send to the user.

However the script wont have to run on the visitors Browser, wich might be faster for slow Computers.

For each individual case you will have to measure the time and see what's better. In your case I would say use PHP, the impact wont be too significant.

Answer (score 1):

Webservers like Apache, Tomcat, or Nginx are optimized to serve PHP files quickly. Just switching the file name to .php won't slow it down. Unless your PHP script is doing something time-intensive, you won't notice a performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

It will technically be slower, although immeasurable by any non-benchmark standards, i'm sure.

You're adding another layer in between the request and the response, and that is the preprocessing of PHP code. You likely will not notice any performance decrease, as most web sites are written in a server-side scripting language such as PHP, ASP, CGI, Python, etc; and even some off the largest/most complicated sites in the world still load quite quickly. Servers are designed and built to handle advanced processing of code.

The functionality and reliability you're offered by server side scripting as opposed to JavaScript interpretation on the client-side far outweighs almost any negatives of using PHP or any other SS scripting language.

In short: Yes and no, but mostly no.